# *** HAPPY BIRTHDAY TO US ***

Tags: discussion

Along with a few other Stack Exchange sites, **Network Engineering went online *ten years ago***. So, happy birthday to all of us!

[image]

*Image credit: [it depends networks](https://twitter.com/itdependsnet/status/721111052822429696)*

Our community is growing on a somewhat small scale but that's most likely due to our sharp focus on enterprise networks and products. It's not the quantity but the quality that counts. Keep going!

At this point, we'd like to ask you as a community member for your short story on how you found Network Engineering!

Cheers!

Comment: Congratulations Network Engineering. I can't wait to hear people's stories.

Comment: I just realized that I joined barely a month after this site was created.  You don't really expect me to remember what I was googling ten years ago, do you? :)

Comment: Happy Birthday! Been here just about this whole time and the start of Stack Exchange. Love this community.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was there from the beginning when the site was launched on Area 51.

My first email received regarding this site was this:

```
From: Stack Exchange Area 51 <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
To: (ME)
Subject: Private beta invitation for Network Engineering Q&A site - Area 51 - Stack Exchange
Date: Tue, 07 May 2013 20:04:56 +0000

Good news everyone!

The proposal to create a Network Engineering Stack Exchange site has moved on to private beta!

This is a site for network engineers.
```

I don't remember that much from these early days, only that it was REALLY REALLY hard to convince StackExchange and some users from ServerFault that Network Engineering is NOT AT ALL like server administration and that ServerFault is not a good home for network related questions. Thankfully in the end people agreed or at least stopped complaining enough for the site to start. :)

Also the current design was the second attempt, we didn't particularly like the first one and suggested to use a somewhat abstract router stencil which became the O in NetwOrk Engineering.

I'm happy that we're still here (and can't believe it has been 10 years already). On to the next decade.